# PHP Regexp Help

Tags: php

I'm going to be working with regular expression's a lot in a new project,
I don't have much experience with them and was wondering of a good way of converting HTML to a regular expression.

Anybody know of any good tutorials, or perhaps a generator?

At the moment I need to convert this:

```
<span class="code" id="code" title="DOESNT MATTER">IMPORTANT<img class="scissors" src="DOESNT MATTER" alt="DOESNT MATTER" /></span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: RegEx + HTML = bad. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: I am I'm just modifying it to make it suite my needs, so I thought maybe this would be a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just get rid of all the html around some values, you can just use [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)

Edit: moved the comment into the answer because it was copy/pasting out bad.

```
<?php
$html = '<span class="code" id="code" title="DOESNT MATTER">IMPORTANT<img class="scissors" src="DOESNT MATTER" alt="DOESNT MATTER" /></span>';
preg_match_all("/<span\s.*?class=\"code\"[^>]+>(.*?)<img\s.*?class=\"scissors\"[^>]+>/i", $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Also, please note that just like said in the comments above, using a regex to parse html is considered bad practice. You should be able to load the html into an instance of DOMDocument and use the getElementsByTagName method to get all spans. Then you can loop through those and validate the attributes/text inside.

Comment: Yes, but I have a big file of HTML and I'm looking for multiple of the basically same lines. I need the IMPORTANT and nothing else from each.

Comment: so what exactly are you looking for? if you just wanted to match 'IMPORTANT'  then `/IMPORTANT/` would do it. What exactly makes 'IMPORTANT' important? Is it like a span tag with the class code followed by some text that you want to capture followed by an image tag with the class scissors? `preg_match_all("/<span\s.*?class=\"code\"[^>]+>(.*?)<img\s.*?class=\"scissors\"[^>]+>/i", $html, $matches);var_dump($matches);`

Comment: Didn't seem to find anything? :/

Comment: .. and yes I'm looking to output the text in the span tag.

Comment: This is what I'm using at the moment: `code`preg_match_all("/<span\s.*?class=\"code\"[^>]+>(.*?)<img\s.*?class=\"scissors\"[‌​^>]+>/i", $printable, $matches);

      foreach($matches as $match)
      {
echo("$match[1]<br />");
      }`code`

Comment: It didn't copy paste well. I moved it into the answer.

Comment: Seems to be getting there, the only problem is that it's not picking up on all the similar span's in the html.

Comment: It's perfect I just had to add an "PREG_SET_ORDER". Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = '<span class="code" id="code" title="DOESNT MATTER">IMPORTANT<img class="scissors" src="DOESNT MATTER" alt="DOESNT MATTER" /></span>';
preg_match('|<span class="code" id="code" title="DOESNT MATTER">IMPORTANT<img class="scissors" src="DOESNT MATTER" alt="DOESNT MATTER" /></span>|', $text, $match);
```

there's nothing to be "converted" if you're not looking for specified title for example

to pick that important you would use

```
$text = '<span class="code" id="code" title="DOESNT MATTER">IMPORTANT<img class="scissors" src="DOESNT MATTER" alt="DOESNT MATTER" /></span>';
preg_match('|<span class="code" id="code" title="DOESNT MATTER">(.*?)<img class="scissors" src="DOESNT MATTER" alt="DOESNT MATTER" /></span>|', $text, $match);
echo $match[1]; //IMPORTANT
```

Comment: How would I go about picking up the "IMPORTANT"?

Comment: Seem to output just one character?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that Regular Expressions are not a great solution for parsing HTML. I think they are fine if you have a small chunk of HTML with a guaranteed format, though.

Please see the following great StackOverflow thread:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)